# Flutter GetX: Where Does Get.put Go in a Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am new to [GetX](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/) and am trying to learn how to use it. I have read different tutorials that inject the controller **outside** of the widget's `build` method, and others that put it **inside** it.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key:key);

  //Outside...
  final controller = Get.put(Controller()); //<---

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Inside...
    final controller = Get.put(Controller()); //<---

    return Obx(
      () => Text(controller.name)
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a difference between those two locations? If so, why?

Also, where should it go in a `StatefulWidget`? It seems it should **not** go inside the `build` method because it causes a stack overflow error for me.

Does the location of `Get.put()` matter inside a widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way is to put the controller outside the widget, so it will be created once. if you but it inside the widget a new instance of the controller will be created each time you refresh (update) the widget.
Also, with `GetX` there is no need to use `StatefulWidget`.

Answer (score 2):

The answers shared are correct. Thank you! I wanted to post another answer that I consider to be an even better way to do it as [referenced in the documentation](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md#other-ways-of-using-it).

This method allows for controller access **without ever putting `Get.put` in any of your widgets**. This is also really helpful if you have a lot of controllers and need to reference them in widgets as well as from other controllers.

Here is an example:

```dart
//ControllerA
class ControllerA extends GetxController {
  static ControllerA get to => Get.find();

  final name = 'Bob'.obs;

  someMethod(){
    ControllerB.to.anotherMethod(); //'I am inside ControllerB!'
  }
}

//ControllerB
class ControllerB extends GetxController {
  //+++
  static ControllerB get to => Get.find();

  anotherMethod(){
    print('I am inside ControllerB!');
  }
}
```

And then inside Widgets:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key:key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Obx(
      () => Text(ControllerA.to.name) //Bob
    );
  }
}
```

This requires that you add your `Get.put` declarations in `main.dart` so that you make sure they are all ready:

```dart
void main() {
  Get.put(ControllerA());
  Get.put(ControllerB());

  runApp(
    GetMaterialApp(...)
  );
}
```

In my opinion, it's really clean like this--and very convenient!

Answer (score 2):

If we want to keep a GetX controller **in memory forever**, then we should indeed instantiate it outside of a Widget's `build()` function (such as within `main()` as Clifton shows).

(Note that we can also use `GetXService` for persistent controllers, which allows manual disposal.)

Placing controllers **inside** `build()` functions, *is* the correct place when we want GetX to **free memory** & dispose the controller when the widget goes "out of scope".  (e.g. when the user has "popped" the route from the stack.)  There's also no danger in "recreating" the controller when its instantiated inside `build()`: Get checks for existence of a controller when `Get.put()` is called and skips it if the controller is already instantiated.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69337442/2301224) (and link to an explanation by one of Get's maintainers) for more info on why we should `Get.put()` inside `build()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you put it inside the `build` method, it will create a new instance every time the widget is rebuilt, so it is better to but it outside and in most cases I think you do not need to use `StatefulWidget`with `GetX` even in animation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @clifton-labrum answer. Read it first.

Controller Sample :

```
//ControllerA
class ControllerA extends GetxController {
  static ControllerA get to {
    try{
      return Get.find<ControllerA>();
    } catch (e){
      return Get.put(ControllerA());
    }
  }

  final name = 'Bob'.obs;
}
```

Widget Sample :

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key:key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Obx(
      () => Text(ControllerA.to.name) //Bob
    );
  }
}
```

Implementing this way you don't need to declare anything on `main.dart`.